# What is the difference between helix and spiral?

Tags: geometry, terminology, curves

The words *spiral* and *helix* are both used for curves that "wind around". For example, both searches "DNA spiral" and "DNA helix" (with quotation marks) result in many thousands of Google hits.

Is  there a difference between helix and spiral, or are these words synonyms?

Answer (score 5):

A helix is a curve in 3-d space with an axis, where the tangent line makes a constant angle with the axis. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix) for some info on the helix. A circle would be the only helix which could lie in a plane, since the tangent line to a plane curve is always at 90 degrees from an axis normal to that plane. So a 2-d helix is not much of a helix, which more typically resemble corkscrews.

[Note: I take that back about plane curves --- the tangent line to *any* curve in the $xy$ plane (at any point on it) is at a 90 degree angle from the $z$ axis, so that any curve in the $xy$ plane would qualify as a helix under the constant angle definition. That makes such curves not good candidates for the term ""helix", i.e. the notion is trivially true for all plane curves.]

Spirals on the other hand do not need to have that property, and are typically curves in a 2-d plane. See the link [here](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/spiral.htm) for some information about various types of spiral. Some of them are quite interesting.

Comment: So how would the Venn diagram for spirals and helices look like?